# Where does elementor stores the data from the content that is created from the frontend view?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to change a value/text in page created by elementor page builder plugin that exists on around 400 pages. I have edited the database (wp_posts) with the right values but it's not changed on the front end. The values are still the old values on the pages. It almost seems like something is being cached somewhere, but I do not have any caching currently enabled.

If I completely disable elementor and elementor pro. The correct values are shown. If I re-enable elementor the old incorrect values are shown again.

Does anyone know where does elementor stores the data from the content that is created from the frontend view? In the database (where?) in files? (where?) Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 24):

Elementor stores the data in postmeta table. For each page/post id the page data is stored in meta key "_elementor_data".

Comment: Some systems append a "wp_", or similar, to make name "wp_postmeta"